# Has any one worked with IBM Net.Data

Tags: ibm-midrange

We have a small old project in **[Net.data](http://www.ibm.com/systems/i/software/netdata/)**
where some development is still occurring.

I have the IBM manuals for this product.

Does anyone know of any tutorial or other source of information on this language?  I was unable to locate any results using Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this useful?

Net.Data Adminstration and Programming Guide: http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_i_software_netdata_dtwa2mst.pdf

Net.Data Reference: http://www.ibm.com/systems/i/software/netdata/db2rn.pdf

IBM Net.Data for i Samples: http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/netdata/samples/sample.html

Try the **IBM search** instead:

http://www.ibm.com/search/csass/search?sn=mh&q=net.data&lang=en&cc=zz&en=utf

Comment: This is useful :-) but i have this already... just like this 2 more docs i have from  ibm (manuals). am just trying find that is that the only 3 documents available for this language!!! :-(

Answer (score 3):

There is a fantastic forum http://dtwdude.com which I have used for over 10 years. I trust you will find it as useful as I do

Comment: I upvoted to get you back to one because that does look like a good resource.

Comment: ...and now this site now redirects to a Chinese site.  :(

Answer (score 2):

You can also ask questions on [WEB400](http://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/web400) I know there are several on there that have at least used it in the past. You aren't alone, but most seem to be switching to PHP lately.

Comment: Mike, the link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is still relevant, I find http://www.thedance.net/~roth/websphere/netdata/ the fastest and easiest reference on a day-day basis.